# options strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'string' to 'date'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I have a issue in asp.net with datetime, I am trying to use datetime for textbox, I can type the datetime into the textbox. When I convert textbox to datetime it has an error.

Code:

```
Dim startdate As DateTime = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: `Format` returns a `String`, but you have defined `startdate` as a `DateTime`. One way to fix this just get rid of the `Format()` command. However, `CDate` is not recommended, as it depends on the date settings on your computer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433061/741136

Comment: what if I still want to use CDate

Comment: You can't, really, unless you want to do some string mangling. `CDate` does not allow you to set the date format, it leaves it to the user to do that in Control Panel

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are trying to achieve is to convert a date that the user enters in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. If so, try this:

```
Dim startdate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```